# SOAP request works in SOAP UI but It is not working with python Requests library

Tags: python, web-services, soap, python-requests, wsdl

I'm trying to do a SOAP Request from code. So I used SOAP UI to test the Webservice, it is necessary to pass a certificate.pem, after run the request its working as follows.

[image: expected response]
[image: request info]
[image: endpoint information]

I decided to test the soap request just using requests library using the same xml request from SOAP UI as you can see in the following code:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

cert_file="path to cert"
key_file="path to key"

endpoint='https://cifinpruebas.asobancaria.com/InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial?wsdl'
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user", "password")

body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inf="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <inf:consultaXml soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <in0 xsi:type="dto:ParametrosConsultaDTO" xmlns:dto="http://dto.infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
            <codigoInformacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1401</codigoInformacion>
            <motivoConsulta xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">24</motivoConsulta>
            <numeroIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">80775779</numeroIdentificacion>
            <tipoIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1</tipoIdentificacion>
        </in0>
    </inf:consultaXml>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

body = body.encode('utf-8')
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, cert=(cert_file, key_file))
print(response)
```

I was using the RSA PRIVATE KEY and the Certificate, but in the response I got the following error:

```
<Response [500]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>  
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode
                xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction
            </faultcode>   
            <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>  
            <detail>
                <ns2:hostname
                    xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ttuweb3
                </ns2:hostname>  
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So it is a server error (error 500), but I'm so confused as I said the request is working using SOAP UI but not in python. Any explanation about it?

**NOTE:** I have been using Zeep library too, but the result is quite the same.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ttuweb3.universo.corp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f993b793c40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

**edit 1: Update the header**
I added the following code and the before error was solved.
session.headers.update({"SOAPAction": ""})

but new error appears.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: Request does not contain required Security header</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname
                    xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ttuweb3
                </ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: well the error says `no SOAPAction header` have you tried adding a soap action header in your python request? `session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "SOAPAction": ""}`

Comment: Yes, in edit 1. I did, but I can’t solve the security header.